# jQuery selector for selecting an element by comparing its two data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i want to select an element by comparing its two data attributes, if they are equal or not. Is it possible, and if yes, how? as an example, i need to select an li

```
<li data-prevstate="true" data-currstate="false">
```

where the previous state and current state is equal.

Comment: Could you provide any codes please ?

Comment: edited the question, sorry i accidentally used the quote instead of code formatting n it vanished coz of the opening angled bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<li data-prevstate="true" data-currstate="false">
<li data-prevstate="true" data-currstate="false">
<li data-prevstate="true" data-currstate="true">
<li data-prevstate="true" data-currstate="false">
<li data-prevstate="true" data-currstate="true">
```

May be this.?

```
 $('li').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).data('prevstate') == $(this).data('currstate'); 
 });
```

This will select two elements from the set of elements which are given above.

Comment: Again (from another comment), why aren't you doing `$(this).data('prevstate') == $(this).data('currstate')`? Other than that though, this is the best, most concise answer

Comment: @Bojangles Answer Updated in accordance with your comment. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2):

May be this ?

```
var selected = '';
$('li').each(function() {
  if($(this).attr('data-prevstate') == $(this).attr('data-currstate')) {
  selected = $(this);
}
});
```

Now you can do any action with `selected`

OR as suggested:

```
var selected = '';
$('li').each(function() {
  if($(this).data('prevstate') == $(this).data('currstate')) {
  selected = $(this);
}
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing `$(this).data('prevstate') == $(this).data('currstate')`?

Comment: @Bojangles I was not sure about that. Thanks for updating my JS info. :)

Comment: i know this approach, but i was hoping to avoid any looping. doing it with a single selector, i mean like checking if the length of the elements selected is > 1, to be more clear, a selector that would simply select elements with both attributes equal.

Comment: @i8taken I am not sure about any such selector. I think looping is needed. I am open to new findings though ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li data-prev="abc" data-curr="abc">Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li data-prev="abc" data-curr="abc">Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li data-prev="abc" data-curr="abc">Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>

<script>
     $(document).ready( function(){
       var matches = [];
       $('li').each( function( i, o ){
           $o = $(o);
           if( $o.data('prev') == $o.data('curr') ) 
               matches.push($o);
       });
       console.log(matches);
     });
</script>
```

Will get all the li items whose current and previous data matches